# Can't suspend on Acer Aspire One 722 using proprietary AMD drivers

Tags: suspend, battery, ati

I have an Acer Aspire One 722 netbook with a C60 CPU and a ATI Radeon™ HD 6250 GPU. I am trying to decrease the power usage and have tried Jupiter and Powertop, but the lowest power usage has been by installing the proprietary driver. I installed the most recent driver from the amd website (amd-driver-installer-12-3-x86.x86_64.run) and the power consumption is very, but now the system won't resume from suspend.

This site says suspend works (I tried editing the /etc/X11/xorg.conf mentioned, but it didn't fix the issue)
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide#Suspend.2FHibernation

but this site says it doesn't
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne522#Suspend_and_hibernate

I am running 11.04 with kernel 3.0.0-12

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.fuduntu.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2127) shows some hope. I havent try it yet, but I'm prety sure that the problem may not be the problem. Maybe it's something related in the order of loading the driver options after resume from suspend, or something to do with the previous driver state saved on suspension--like first thing to do after suspend is to shutdown the screen and last thing todo after resume from suspend is to start the screen.

Also its known that if you try to login pointing to the center of the screen, it could be posible to start the screen again.

Maybe if there is a way to unlock the function keys before login then we could test trying to force the screen to turn on.